# validate checkbox or dropdown list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i just need help with this, i still can't found how to make it.

first i want to validate that the user select one of 3 checkbox before he can enter a value to the textbox.

```
<div><p>

            <%= Html.CheckBox("cbCodigo") %> <label class="inline" for="Codigo">Codigo</label>
            <%= Html.CheckBox("cbNombreCliente") %> <label class="inline" for="NombreCliente">Nombre del cliente</label>
            <%= Html.CheckBox("cbCiudad") %> <label class="inline" for="Ciudad">Ciudad</label>
        </p></div>
        <div><p>
            <label>Valor para la Consulta: </label>
            <%=Html.TextBox("tbCodCliente") %>
        </p></div>
```

and then how can validate that the user select one of option different of null from a dropdown list

this is how i validate the textbox

```
$("#formConsClientes").validate({
                rules: {
                    tbCodCliente: { required: true }
                },
                messages: {
                    tbCodCliente: { required: "Nombre usuario es un campo obligatorio" }
                },
                errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the textbox to readonly until a checkbox is clicked. Then in the onclick of the checkboxes, enable editing. Give the checkboxes a `class` so you can just use one function for all three checkboxes.

```
$(".checkboxes").click(function(){
    $('#tbCodCliente').removeAttr('readonly');
});
```